# Inverse image of sum of ideals

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, ring-isomorphism

Lately, I've been looking for nice identities involving ring homomorphisms and ideals. For example, I've been able to prove that for an epimorphism $\varphi:R\to S$ and two ideals $I,J\subset R$ we have $\varphi(I+J)=\varphi(I)+\varphi(J)$; or that for a principal ideal $(a)$, $a\in R$, we have $\varphi( (a) )=(\varphi(a))$.

Now I'm wondering what would happen to two ideals $I',J'\subset S$, using $\varphi^{-1}$. When does it hold that $\varphi^{-1}(I'+J')=\varphi^{-1}(I')+\varphi^{-1}(J')$? I got one contention:

> If $r\in\varphi^{-1}(I')+\varphi^{-1}(J')$ then $\exists\, i\in\varphi^{-1}(I'),j\in\varphi^{-1}(J'):r=i+j\Rightarrow\varphi(r)=\varphi(i)+\varphi(j)\in I'+J'\Rightarrow r\in\varphi^{-1}(I'+J')$

For the other contention I first got stuck at

> If $r\in\varphi^{-1}(I'+J')$ then $\varphi(r)=i'+j',i'\in I', j'\in J'$

where I have to assume $\varphi$ is surjective to say $\exists\, i,j: \varphi(i)=i',\varphi(j)=j'$.

But then I got

> $\varphi(r)=\varphi(i+j)$

and I'd say I need to conclude $r=i+j$, but for that I'd need $\varphi$ to be injective (hence an isomorphism).

Is it really necessary to assume $\varphi$ is an isomorphism? I found a counterexample where $\varphi$ is injective, but nor surjective, so I'd say we need surjectivity; but I'm not able to find a counterexample where $\varphi$ is surjective, but not injective.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are likely aware of this, but just to make sure: $\varphi(I)$ and $\varphi(J)$ are not in general ideals of $S$, even if $\varphi$ is an epimorphism. for instance, the inclusion map $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ is an epimorphism, but $\varphi(I)$ is not an ideal of $\mathbb{Q}$ for any non-zero ideal $I\leqslant \mathbb{Z}$. if $\varphi$ is *surjective* then the result does hold, but epimorphisms of unital rings are not in general surjective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a counter example in which $\phi$ is injective but not surjective, consider:

- $S=R\oplus R$,
- $\phi(x) =(x,x)$,
- $I= R\oplus 0$, and
- $J=0\oplus R$.

When $\phi$ is surjective the missing inclusion may be proved as follows: write $\phi(r)=i'+j'$ and pick $s$ in $R$ such that $\phi(s)=i'$.  Then
$$
\phi(r-s) = j'$$
whence $r-s\in \phi^{-1}(J')$ and clearly $s\in \phi^{-1}(I').$

We then have
$$
r= s +(r-s) \in \phi^{-1}(I')+\phi^{-1}(J').
$$